# converting from String to JSONArray or JSONObject in Java

Tags: java, json, twitter

I'm trying to use the JSON library to consume twitter information from the get search feature. I'm getting the error:
     A JSONArray text must start with '[' at 1 [character 2 line 1]

So it's basically in the wrong form. Some people are saying this needs to be an object but everytime I call the constructor it says that it can't take a String as input. How do I get this string into the form of a JSONArray so that I can access it's elements.

Here is my code:

```
URL twitterSource = new URL("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=google");
ByteArrayOutputStream urlOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

IOUtils.copy(twitterSource.openStream(), urlOutputStream);
String urlContents = urlOutputStream.toString();

// parse JSON
System.out.println(urlContents);
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(urlContents);

// use
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("id"));
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("text"));               
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getString("created_at"));
}
```

my print statement shows the string contains:

```
{"completed_in":0.318,"max_id":144850937012428800,"max_id_str":"144850937012428800","next_page":"?page=2.....................
```

This is a string in the form of a JSON object but it is not actually an object. It's still a string. I'm printing a String.  HOw can I get this into an Object or better yet a JSONArray so that I can actually access its elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a JSON *object*, not an array.

Comment: Thanks. How can I access the elements of a JSON object?

Comment: Which object are your referring to?  urlContents is a string. Which i'm passing to the constructor of JSONArray().  I didn't post the complete string of the JSON file but it is in JSON format with many elements which have content I want.

Comment: If you're saying urlContents is an JSON object how do I then convert it to an array? shouldn't  "new JSONArray(urlContent)" do that?

Comment: **It isn't an array**.  You cannot magically turn an object into an array.

Comment: no but you could turn a properly formated object with a predefined structure into an array using a method.

Comment: It might be in the form of an object but it's still a string. How can I get it into an object or json array so I can perform some operations on it.  urlContents contains the data and it's typeis String. I need access to its elements.

Comment: `new JSONObject(urlContents)`?

Comment: That worked this time. I think when I tried that I still had a dependency problem with the way I imported the JSON library. Any suggestions on either converting the JSON object to an array or getting the elements directly from the object?

Comment: It isn't an array, and you can't magically turn it into an array.  You can call `getString()`.

Comment: I just want to point out that there is a way to turn an object into an array through one of the JSON methods. In case anyone elese is reading this.

Comment: good but you should have given the method name or code snippet so that it could have helped some like me